# Solution set of inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is the question:

$$\frac{1-2x-3x^2}{3x-x^2-5} \gt 0$$

What I did :

I got the answer as 
$$\left(x-3\right)\left(x+1\right) \gt 0$$

giving me the solution set : $x \in (-\infty,-1 )\cup(3,\infty)$
but the answer is $x \in (-\infty,-1 )\cup(\frac{1}{3},\infty)$

where am i going wrong?

Comment: how did you get $(x-3)(x+1)$?

Answer (score 2):

Just note
$$\frac{1-2x-3x^2}{3x-x^2-5}>0\iff\frac{3x^2+2x-1}{x^2-3x+5}>0\iff\frac{(3x-1)(x+1)}{(x-\frac{3}{2})^2+\frac{11}{4}}>0$$
Since $(x-3/2)^2+11/4>0$ for every real number $x$ we need $(3x-1)(x+1)>0$, this is achieved iif $x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(\frac{1}{3},\infty)$.

Comment: Ya i did exactly the same thing. just factorised the numerator wrongly. THank you for your reply. iam such a fool.

Answer (score 2):

The numerator is $-3x^2-2x+1=-(x+1)(3x-1)$ while the denominator is $-x^2+3x-5<0$.

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: actually it was a factorising error of numerator (while applying quad formula) thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.